# Refactor a if-elif-block into a pythonic dictionary

Tags: python, lambda

I have a big `if-elif-else` block in my code like this

```
if counted == 2:
    score = None

elif counted == 1:
    score = (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100

elif counted == 0:
    score = (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100

else:
    raise Exception('Should not be reached!')
```

With python I assume there is a way to solve that with a `dict` using the `counted` values as keys. But what comes as items into that dict? The new `case` expression is not an option here. IMHO this wouldn't be pythonic no matter that it's now part of Python standard.

## Approach A

```
# Approach A
mydict = {
    0: ((sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: ((sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: None
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted])
```

The problem here is that all items are *executed*.

```
{0: 4625.0, 1: 6183.333333333334, 2: None}
```

## Approach B

```
mydict = {
    0: (lambda _: (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: (lambda _: (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: (lambda _: None)
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted](None))
```

Here I have the *fake argument* I don't need. But it seems to be mandatory when creating a `lambda`.

```
{0: <function <lambda> at 0x7ff8f3dce040>, 1: <function <lambda> at 0x7ff8f3b6a670>, 2: <function <lambda> at 0x7ff8f3b6a700>}
```

Is there a another way?

## Full MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random

values = random.choices(range(100), k=10)
counted = random.choice(range(3))

print(f'counted={counted}')

if counted == 2:
    score = None

elif counted == 1:
    score = (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100

elif counted == 0:
    score = (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100

else:
    raise Exception('Should not be reached!')

print(f'score={score}')

# Approach A
mydict = {
    0: ((sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: ((sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: None
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted])

# Approach B
mydict = {
    0: (lambda _: (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: (lambda _: (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: (lambda _: None)
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted](None))
```

Comment: Side note: `f'foo={foo}'` can be replaced with `f'{foo=}'`. In fact, `foo` can be any expression.

Comment: Are there just three possible values for *counted*? If so then a short *if/else* or *match* construct is ideal

Comment: It's not mandatory to have an argument in a lambda function. You can just call `lambda: print('hello')` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lambda`s without the arguments works. Just needs the `:`

```py
import random


values = random.choices(range(100), k=10)

mydict = {
    0: lambda: (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100,
    1: lambda: (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100,
    2: lambda: None
}

counted = random.choice(range(3))
mydict[counted]()
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need any arguments for lambda:

```
mydict = {
    0: (lambda: (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: (lambda: (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: (lambda: None)
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted]())
```

That being said, arguably the most Pythonic version would be version 0, if/else chain. It is most readable, calculates only what is necessary and doesn't overcomplicate anything.

Comment: It does "overcomplicate" things in my case where the cyclomatic complexity is to high. That is why I refactoring that code. I know there are other approaches to reduce cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: Agreed. The dictionary / lambda arrangement results in a completely unnecessary obfuscation. People tend to forget that the code they write may have to be maintained by someone else in the future so why make it unreadable for the sake of... what?

Comment: @buhtz your A and B only "reduce" this complexity because you calculate everything and not just what you actually need. That's kinda like saying you have O(1) algorithm because you hardcoded all possible results.

Comment: @buhtz: You have three paths through your code that need to be tested in all versions.  The dictionary solution functions like an if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on globals is usually a bad idea:

```
mydict = {
    0: (lambda values: (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: (lambda values: (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: (lambda _: None)
}

print(mydict)
print(mydict[counted](values))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a dictionary with lambda values merely serves to obfuscate the code. Furthermore it's difficult to understand for lesser beings than the OP. It also doesn't perform very well.

Here's a consolidation of 3 possible approaches with output that demonstrates how they each perform:

```
from timeit import timeit

values = [1, 2, 3, 4,]

mydict = {
    0: (lambda _: (sum(_) - 4) / 8 * 100),
    1: (lambda _: (sum(_) - 3) / 6 * 100),
    2: (lambda _: None)
}

def v1(): # dictionary / lambda approach
    for i in range(3):
        score = mydict[i](values)
    return score

def v2(): # match / case approach
    for i in range(3):
        match i:
            case 0:
                score = (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100
            case 1:
                score = (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100
            case _:
                score = None
    return score

def v3(): # simple if/else
    for i in range(3):
        if i == 0:
            score = (sum(values) - 4) / 8 * 100
        elif i == 1:
            score = (sum(values) - 3) / 6 * 100
        else:
            score = None
    return score


for func in v1, v2, v3:
    print(func.__name__, timeit(func))
```

**Output:**

```
v1 0.5237932950003596
v2 0.4183016259994474
v3 0.40317739200327196
```

**Conclusion:**

Keep it simple and clear and you'll very likely gain in terms of performance and maintainability

Comment: It really surprises me that the dict approach is the slower then if-then-else. Thanks. But I'm still have the opinion that a dict is easier to read because of less indentions.